# Is the host of a FTP server anonymous?

Tags: networking, ftp

I want to open an FTP server for clients to upload files to. I'm wondering if the host of an FTP is anonymous (e.g. would my public IP address be leaked, or any other data that could connect the server to myself)?

If the typical configuration of an FTP server is not anonymous on the host's end, what measures can one implement to make it anonymous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse it is not anonymous. The clients need the public IP - how else would you expect them to connect to your server?

The IP can not be linked to you by everybody - but your ISP can do that.

The "anonymous ftp" you might have heard about, refers to the passwordless useraccount on the server, which can be used by anybody.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Virsacer - are there any other protocols that allow users to upload files, but keeps me anonymous?

Comment: @JessieToldt Think of the internet like traditional mail. It doesn't matter how you send a package (data), there always has to be an address to receive it (your server). You can use a house or a PO Box, or send it through multiple relays, but people have to know where to deliver whatever is being sent. Senders can be anonymous, those receiving things (effectively) can't.